# Making a vertical grid take up the entire screen for all screen sizes - compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on creating a 3x4 grid containing 12 images, each accompanied by text at the bottom, serving as options in my application. However, I'm encountering two issues with the LazyVerticalGrid:

1. I'm having difficulty making the grid items clickable.
2. I'm struggling to extend the grid to fill the entire screen height. This is what ive came up with so far:

Im new and open to suggestions, if there is a better way to do it
Thanks in advance! :)

```
@Composable
private fun MainLayout(viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
    val imageList = listOf( ... )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(120.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(8.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            items(imageList.size) { index ->
                ImageWithText(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(4.dp),
                    imageID = imageList[index],
                    text = "Item $index"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ImageWithText(imageID: Int, text: String, modifier: Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = imageID),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(140.dp)
                .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.small)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                .padding(8.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Text(text = text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your two questions per my knowledge:

1.) You can make a Composable clickable by adding the [`clickable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clickable(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.Function0)) Modifier. You can simply use it like this:

```
@Composable
private fun ImageWithText(imageID: Int, text: String, modifier: Modifier, onClick: (clickedText: String) -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.clickable { onClick(text) },
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
       //...
    }
}
```

In your case, you would pass in a callback function to the Composable and manage it in the parent Composable:

```
items(imageList.size) { index ->
            ImageWithText(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(4.dp),
                imageID = imageList[index],
                text = "Item $index",
                onClick = { clickedText -> 
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Item with Text $clickedText was clicked")
                }
            )
        }
```

2.) Your [`LazyVerticalGrid`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-grids) already fills up the whole screen because you use `fillMaxSize()`. If you want to distribute the items so that the whole screen is perfectly filled, this is not possible. With `LazyVerticalGrid`, each item needs to define its own absolute size.

> LazyVerticalGrid lets you specify a width for items, and then the grid will fit as many columns as possible.

If you always have exactly 12 items and want them to display in equal size, no matter how big the phone screen is, try something as folloiws:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(1f)) {
        ImageWithText(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(4.dp),
            imageID = imageList[0],
            text = "Item 1"
       )
       //...
       // repeat ImageWithText Composable two more times
    }
    //...
    // repeat Row Composable three more times

}
```

Of course, you can also use Kotlin loops to simplify this.

Finally, some more things I noticed about your code:

- You don't need both `fillMaxSize` and `fillMaxHeight`. The Modifier `fillMaxSize` already includes `fillMaxHeight` and `fillMaxWidth`.
- Your `Box` Composable currently appears to be useless, as the Box only has one child. You probably can remove it.
- You could also use [`itemsIndexed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/LazyGridScope#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridScope).itemsIndexed(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function2,kotlin.Function3,kotlin.Function2,kotlin.Function3)) instead of items. See the sample below:

---

```
itemsIndexed(imageList) { index, item ->
            ImageWithText(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(4.dp),
                imageID = item,
                text = "Item $index"
            )
        }
```

Comment: It's impossible with lazyverticalgrid? Is it possible any other way?

Comment: If the number of items in the grid is always fixed, you can build a grid by creating a `Column` and then putting the desired number of `Row` into the `Column`. Finally, you can make every item use the same space by using the `weight` Modifier.

Comment: If you have a dynamic number of images, `LazyVerticalGrid` is the right approach. You could in theory measure the height of the screen and then calculate how high each item can be so that all rows fit perfectly. But this does not make very much sense, as depending on the number of images, the Grid should start scrolling anyway.

Comment: I have a fixed 12 item grid, maybe LazyVertialGrid isn't the right choice.

Comment: I edited my post and included an example how to create a static grid. I hope this helps you!